# Python NLTK - Making a 'Dictionary' from a Corpus and Saving the Number Tags

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

I'm not super experienced with Python, but I want to do some Data analytics with a corpus, so I'm doing that part in NLTK Python.

I want to go through the entire corpus and make a dictionary containing every word that appears in the corpus dataset. I want to be able to then search for a word in this dictionary and find the number of times that this word appeared as what part of speech (tag). So, for example, if I were to search for 'dog' I might find 100 noun tags and 5 verb tags, etc.

The final goal is to externally save this file as .txt or something and load it in another program to check probability of a word being which tag..

Would I do this with Counter and ngrams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want the POS of loose words you don't need ngrams, you need a tagged corpus. Assuming your corpus is already tagged, you can do it like this.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> wordcounts = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(brown.tagged_words())
>>> wordcounts["set"].tabulate(10)
VBN   VB   NN  VBD VBN-HL NN-HL 
159   88   86   71    2    2
```

A `ConditionalFreqDist` is basically a dictionary of `Counter` objects, with some extras thrown in. Look it up in the NLTK docs.

PS. If you want to case-normalize your words before counting, use

```
wordcounts = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((w.lower(), t) for w, t in brown.tagged_words())
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to work really well! Thanks! Can I use json to print the contents of wordcounts to a text file?

Comment: json.dump(wordcounts, open("corpus_dict.txt",'w')) outputs a text file of nonsense. I'm assuming this is because its a dict of objects?

Comment: I wouldn't know. I'd be really surprised if json doesn't handle nested dictionaries, and that's all they are.

Comment: Ok I was curious; I tried it and it looks perfectly legit. Try `dump = json.dumps(wordcounts)`, and print `dump[:100]`

Comment: Interesting, I can print dump[:100] to a txt file and it gives some "{\"fawn\": {\"NN\": 1}, \"Ranavan\"... but when I print the whole dump it looks like text is being written over top of text

Comment: Are you sure the output is invalid? Have you tried reloading it? (If it just _looks_ invalid, try loading it).

Comment: "text being written on top of text" is not a possible problem in writing out to a file. By default python's json doesn't add newlines or indentation, so you're probably concerned over nothing.